# Why does apply() return incorrect column types?

Tags: r, apply

I've recently started using R and the `apply()` function is tripping me up. I'd appreciate help with this:

```
is.numeric(iris$Sepal.Length) # returns TRUE
is.numeric(iris$Sepal.Width)  # returns TRUE
is.numeric(iris$Petal.Length) # returns TRUE
is.numeric(iris$Petal.Width)  # returns TRUE
```

but,

```
apply(iris, 2, FUN = is.numeric)
```

returns

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
       FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
```

**What's going on?**

Comment: What is function `install`? And see `sapply(iris, is.numeric)`. Also, some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega.

Answer (score 8):

They are all `FALSE` because `apply()` coerces `iris` to a matrix before it applies the `is.numeric()` function.  From `help(apply)` regarding the first argument, `X` -

> If `X` is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), `apply` attempts to coerce it to an array via `as.matrix` if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via `as.array`.

```
is.array(iris)
# [1] FALSE
```

So there you have it. The columns actually all become character after the coercion because a matrix can only take on one data type (see `as.matrix(iris)`). The reason the whole thing is coerced to character and not some other data type is discussed in the *Details* section of `help(as.matrix)`.

As Pascal has noted, you should use `sapply()`.

```
sapply(iris, is.numeric)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE        FALSE
```

Or the slightly more efficient `vapply()`.

```
vapply(iris, is.numeric, NA)
```